# Wordpress- prevent duplication of custom field value

Tags: php, wordpress, field, duplication

I want to check values of `meta-key` called `cf_isbn` already in database in table `wp-postmeta`. If value is repeated, prevent insert content.

I have piece of code, that works correctly if I put `xxxxxxx` value to my ISBN field in frontend post-input, but the main point is change `xxxxxxx` with query to check values already exist in database.

Is there any php wizard who know how to help me?

```
function wpufe_isbn_validation( $errors ) {
    if( $_POST['cf_isbn'] == 'xxxxxxx' ) {
        $errors[] = 'this ISBN is already in database';
    }

    return $errors;
}
add_filter( 'wpuf_add_post_validation', 'wpufe_isbn_validation' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do something like so:

```
function wpufe_isbn_validation( $errors )
{
    global $wpdb;
    $check = $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare("
    SELECT *
    FROM wp-postmeta
    WHERE meta_key = cf_isbn AND meta_value = ".$_POST['cf_isbn']) );


    if(!empty($check))
    {
       return true;
    }
    else
    {
       return false;
    }
}
add_filter( 'wpuf_add_post_validation', 'wpufe_isbn_validation' );
```

Then you can simply execute another function/piece of code depending on what is returned. Obviously if the above returns true, then the ISBN is duplicated and does not need to be inserted.

Comment: Great, but it was not working. I still can add ISBN that already exist in database ;/

Comment: Ołłłł yeah! I edited just this: $check = $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `meta_key` LIKE 'cf_isbn' AND `meta_value` = ".$_POST['cf_isbn']) );  and now works correctly :D

Comment: But there is another problem- it was working only for 'xxxxxxxxxxx' values, not for 'xx-xxx-xxx'. Now I need rebuild function, or delete all "-" value in my table, but only with "meta_key = cf_isbn". Any sugestions?

Comment: Sory for spamming, but well done. by this 
UPDATE `wp_postmeta`  
SET    meta_value = replace(meta_value, '-', '')
WHERE meta_key LIKE 'cf_isbn'

Comment: @KamilPilawka accept the answer if it works for you.